# What's new into the Magento 2.1.6?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.1.6

Today I'm using the Magento CE 2.1.5, what'll be improved with this update? and what are the errors that I could have with this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Highlights

Magento 2.1.6 contains over 15 significant performance enhancements when compared to 2.1.5. Look for the following highlights in this release:

#### Improved performance of the Category page

- loading configurable products from the database is now up to 5x faster
- price calculations are now up to 3-5% faster
- stock validation is now up to 20% faster

#### Optimized image resizing

- image resize operations performed from the command line interface now generate images of all sizes. See magento catalog:images:resize for more information.
- image resize operations from the Admin have been fixed
- significant decrease in the number of file system operations when processing images on frontend
- caching of image metadata is up to 50% faster, depending on store size

#### Improved performance of layered navigation

- layered navigation is now up to 3% faster due to the caching of attribute options

#### Minimized indexing operations after product import

> You can check more bugfixes and details here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.6CE.html

Answer (score 1):

Functional fixes and enhancements

We address the following functional fixes and enhancements in this release.

Catalog

- Magento no longer locks the `category_product_entity` table. Unlocking this table reduces the potential of lock-related timeouts that can occur when indexing and checkout operations run in parallel. Previously, Magento locked the `category_product_entity` table.

- The storefront now displays images that Magento resizes during product save operations, rather than resizing the product on the storefront. Previously, the image path contained `store_id`,  and during save operations, Magento resized images for images the default store only.

- The `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status\getStockId()` method now returns the correct values.

Configurable products

- The check that Magento runs to confirm a configurable product’s readiness for sale is now faster.  (The `isSalable` method checks that a configurable product can be sold (that is, is in a saleable state)).

- Magento no longer calculates configurable product special prices on the category page. Previously, Magento calculated special prices on the category page, but did not display them.

Indexers

- Magento now runs a selective partial re-indexing operation after import if you enabled **Update on Schedule**. Previously, Magento ran a full reindex no matter which index mode was set.

Import

- Magento now displays imported product images in this order: first, the base image, then the additional images in the order in which they were listed in the CSV file. Previously, Magento displayed images in this unexpected order: first, an additional image, then the base image, and finally, all remaining additional images.

Miscellaneous

- Magento now caches attribute options for the layered navigation feature. This reduces the number of queries to the database, and consequently improves performance.

- Magento no longer performs unnecessary file check operations (for example, `file_exists`, `is_file`), which improves the performance of the category and product pages.

- Magento now caches image metadata, which avoids the time-consuming need to read images for metadata loading.

- Magento now shows a significant decrease in Redis traffic after upgrading 2.1.2 to 2.1.4.

Swatches

- Magento no longer creates redundant objects when initializing a configurable product on the Category page.

- You can now disable swatches for both the Catalog page and search results (quick or advanced). To disable swatches from these requests, disable **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Storefront > Show Swatches in Product List**.

- The logic that Magento uses to validate swatch attributes has been optimized.

- Magento now caches swatch data in the block cache, which improves the responsiveness of the configurable product pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer release notes and more information in below link.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.6CE.html